# Sequelize find based on association and nested [Op.and]

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I'm writing here because I'm completely lost. I would like to do a findall based on association and nested `[Op.and]`, but I can't do it. Let me explain.

I have two tables (car and properties) with an association between these two tables (one car, can have several properties). The data looks like this :

```
{
  "car": "BMW M5",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "make",
      "value": "bmw"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "value": "blue"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "car": "AUDI A3",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "make",
      "value": "audi"
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "value": "black"
    }
  ]
},
```

What I'm trying to do is a "findAll" of all cars of make BMW and with blue color. Logically, I would see something like this :

```
( properties.name = make & properties.value = audi ) & ( properties.name = color & properties.value = blue )
```

From this logic, I therefore tried to create the sequelize command below, but without success :

```
const cars = await models.Car.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.Properties,
    required: false,
  }],
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.and]:[
      {[Sequelize.Op.and]: [{"$properties.name$": "make"}, {"$properties.value$": "bmw"}]},
      {[Sequelize.Op.and]: [{"$properties.name$": "color"}, {"$properties.value$": "blue"}]},
    ]
});
```

Apparently when I do this it only takes the last `[Op.and]` (`[Sequelize.Op.and]: [{"$properties.name$": "color"}, {"$properties.value$": "blue"}]`), the others don't seem to be taken into consideration.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I tried several possibilities, but I don't know how to do it. Any help would be very appreciated, thank you in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you over-complicated the `where` condition:

```js
const cars = await models.Car.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: models.Properties,
    required: false,
  }],
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.and]:[
      {
       "$properties.name$": "make",
       "$properties.value$": "bmw"
      },
      {
       "$properties.name$": "color", 
       "$properties.value$": "blue"
      },
    ]
   }
});
```

If you have `different` props in the same group of conditions then you can just use an object to combine them with `AND` operator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, your way of doing is simpler, but the result remains sadly the same. With the include and the combination of these 2 objects it doesn't work. On the other hand with one object it works.

Comment: It seems that we cannot do the next logic : AND( AND(), AND() )

Comment: You need to use two `EXISTS` inside `Sequelize.literal` conditions to check that both records exists (with the made and with the model)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Do you have an example please ? I'm not really an expert in SQL query. Your help will be very appreciated.